# Docker volume for persisting PostgreSQL database data

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm starting a PostgreSQL server with Docker Compose in my MacOS machine:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

When I connect to the server using a database GUI client and create a new database, it works fine. But then, if I restart the container that database does not exist anymore.

```
$ docker stop postgres_db_1
$ docker start postgres_db_1
```

However, if I make changes on the "default" `postgres` database (e.g. create a new table), that change is persisted in the Docker volume successfuly (I restart container and it remains there.)

As you see, I have this volume mapping:

```
./dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Is this mapping correct for all databases inside PostgreSQL server?

Comment: MacOS. With `docker stop postgres_db_1`

Answer (score 0):

The default path `/var/lib/postgresql/data` refers to the place where Postgres data are stored. But if you're using a filesystem mountpoint the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) suggests using subdirectories, for example, `/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata` for the data.

Actually, the storage place can be controlled through the `PGDATA` environment variable on the building stage of a service. The `PGDATA` isn't related to Docker itself, according to the Postgres [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-file-layout.html):

> Traditionally, the configuration and data files used by a database
>   cluster are stored together within the cluster's data directory,
>   commonly referred to as PGDATA (after the name of the environment
>   variable that can be used to define it). A common location for PGDATA
>   is `/var/lib/pgsql/data`.